# How build Custom Helper using other helpers inside the code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, devexpress, razor

I'm creating a custom helper to automate some code in my application. I'd like now how display a control in my helper. When I return the GetHTML() method, the page display the HTML like a plain text. When I use the Render() method the control is rendere in body, out of order.

```
public static string EntityForm(this HtmlHelper helper, Type TypeModel)
{
    return "My Helper" + DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI.ExtensionsFactory.Instance.TextBox(settings =>
            {
                settings.Name = att.Nome;
            }).GetHtml()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `HtmlString`, this way it does not encode the output.

**Example from inside a view**

`@(new HtmlString("<div>some html</div>"))`

**Changing your Html Helper**

Try changing your method to the following:

```
public static HtmlString EntityForm(this HtmlHelper helper, Type TypeModel)
{
    var html = "My Helper" + DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI.ExtensionsFactory.Instance.TextBox(settings =>
            {
                settings.Name = att.Nome;
            }).GetHtml();

    return new HtmlString(html);
}
```

Comment: That's not quite what he's asking for.

Comment: @SLaks, He wants to display html without encoding it, `HtmlString` is the right way to go. The second line is just an example.

Comment: Except that it should be in parentheses, not braces.

Comment: I generally don't touch code in answers.  (although perhaps I should)

Answer (score 0):

Razor will escape all `string`s written to the page.
You need to change your helper method to return an `HtmlString` so that Razor won't escape it.